# react-natiive Avatar element add authorization header for uri attribute

Tags: react-native, authorization-header

I am using the react-native version: "0.63.4". In the Avatar react-native url, I am setting the url value, however, I need to attach an authorization header, with the url. Could someone suggest how do I do it?

```
import {ListItem,Avatar} from 'react-native-elements'
    const CustomListItem = ({id, profilePicture}) => {
        return (
            <ListItem key={id} bottomDivider>
    <ListItem bottomDivider>
                <Avatar rounded 
                 source={{uri:'https://test.url/'+profilePicture}}/>
    
       </ListItem>
        )
    }
export default CustomListItem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avatar's `source` props is based on `ImageSource` of React Native component

[image]

So, in the official docs of react native, you can customize the network request for image like this: (copied from docs)

```
<Image
  source={{
    uri: 'https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Pragma: 'no-cache'
    },
    body: 'Your Body goes here'
  }}
  style={{ width: 400, height: 400 }}
/>
```

More details here: [Network Requests for Images](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images#network-requests-for-images)